# jQuery first level children selector best way

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

What is the best (most productive, less CPU-loading) way to select certain children from ancestor with jQuery?

Let's imagine that we have:

```
<div>
 <b>1</b>
 <p>2</p>
 <a>3</a>
 <p>2</p>
</div>
```

So

`$('div > p')`

or

`$('div').children('p')`

?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-test) I just created `$('div > p')` is about twice as fast. I don't think the two selectors differ in the elements they get back, so the first one may be more desirable, at least from a performance point of view.

Comment: No worries, be sure to bookmark jsPerf, it's a cracking tool to benchmark JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

`$('div > p')` is better and faster for this case

with this one you're parsing the dom one time to find your selector.

in the other case you're parsing it twice : one to find the div element and one to find the p element into the div